# Does the maxTransactionSize set in the NetworkParameters include attachments?

Tags: file, attachment, corda, filesize

Does the maxTransactionSize set in the NetworkParameters include attachments?

I have a situation where I need to send a large file as an attachment and I want to make sure it's less than the maxTransactionSize enforced by the network params.

Answer (score 0):

maxTransactionSize ***does*** include attachments when calculated.

If you want to take a look for yourself, the calculation is done in - WireTransaction.checkTransactionSize: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/transactions/WireTransaction.kt

Unfortunately, the maxTransactionSize is hard coded at 10mb for second for the time being:

```html
 @property maxMessageSize This is currently ignored. However, it will be wired up in a future release.
```

This is an interesting implementation because the file is NOT sent in the initial transaction. In fact, only a hash of the file is included in the transaction itself. Files are only sent to the requesting node *when needed*.

Still, the issue with a large maxTransactionSize is that all nodes must read the entire file into RAM will cause some nodes to fail to verify massive transactions if they have insufficient RAM.

Work is being done to chunk files and enable attachments of arbitrary size!